# How to show an image from ms access to jpanel in java netbeans

Tags: java, jdbc

The code I've used:

```
private void okActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)        
{                                   
    try {
        String Update = name.getText();

        Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:NewPData");
        PreparedStatement psmnt = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT Image FROM Table1 where Name='" + Update + "'");
        ResultSet rs = psmnt.executeQuery();
        Blob blob = rs.getBlob("Image");
        int b;
        InputStream bis = rs.getBinaryStream("Image");

        FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream("Image.jpg");
        while ((b = bis.read()) >= 0) {
            f.write(b);
        }
        f.close();
        bis.close();

        icon = new ImageIcon(blob.getBytes(1L, (int) blob.length()));

        lblImage.setIcon(icon);

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The exception showed:

```
       java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
```

I have first stored the image in ms access and now I want to show it on a label. Please help.

Comment: A bit more information about the error would be useful, like where it's being raised?

Answer (score 3):

This section of code doesn't make sense.

```
Blob blob = rs.getBlob("Image");
int b;
InputStream bis = rs.getBinaryStream("Image");

FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream("Image.jpg");
while ((b = bis.read()) >= 0) {
    f.write(b);
}
f.close();
bis.close();

icon = new ImageIcon(blob.getBytes(1L, (int) blob.length()));
```

You basically read the BLOB from result set to a file and then try and read it again to construct your image.  It's possible that you've exhausted the stream.

Why not just read the image?

```
icon = new ImageIcon("Image.jpg");
```

Better yet, why not take advantage of the `ImageIO` API and read the stream directly, for-going the need to write out a temp file?

```
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(bis); 
icon = image == null ? null : new ImageIcon(image);
```

Comment: Image is my column name in ms access ..i cant understand why it is always saving images named "Long Binary Data" instead of image name??

Comment: I don't understand, what do mean by *"saving images named "Long Binary Data""*?

Comment: in my image column why the name of image shows Long Binary Data when i stored them??

Comment: Because that's how Access stores the data.  It's like when you have a column to store text, it's using "Text".  "Long Binary Data" and "Binary Large Object" are essentially the same thing

Comment: ok now i get it but i tried a lot to show it on a label...i gave dimension also to show it i have used buffer and bytes trick also ..but there is somthing i cant understand i am at last point of my task help me doing it i just want to show that image with employee details on label

Comment: I don't have access at hand to test, need to wait till I get home