# how to display image with jtable netbens

Tags: java, netbeans

when Click the button to display an image on inside a cell in JTable, this takes a text format and shows the image itself.

[image]

[image]

```
public void loading() {

try {

    model =(DefaultTableModel) listofitemtable.getModel();
  
  String[] title = {"auction_no", "auction_name", "auction_type", "auction_date", "points_Per_Team", 
  "minimum_Points", "points_Increase", "Player_per_Team", "image"};

  listofitemtable.getColumn("image").setCellRenderer(new meetable());     
   // model = new DefaultTableModel(null, title);
   // model.setColumnIdentifiers(title);             
    String sql="select * from auction_create";
    model = new DefaultTableModel(null,title){                 
      @Override
       public Class<?> getColumnClass(int column) {
            if (column==8) return ImageIcon.class;
            return Object.class;
        }
    };
   Statement st = conn.createStatement();
     rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
    Object[]fila = new Object[9];
    while(rs.next()){
        fila[0] = rs.getString("auction_no");
        fila[1] = rs.getString("auction_name");
        fila[2] = rs.getString("auction_type");
        fila[3] = rs.getString("auction_date");
        fila[4] = rs.getString("points_Per_Team");
        fila[5] = rs.getString("minimum_Points");
        fila[6] = rs.getString("points_Increase");
        fila[7] = rs.getString("Player_per_Team");          
        fila[8] = new ImageIcon(rs.getBytes("image"));                        
        model.addRow(fila);           
    }         
    // CustomTableModel cusTablModel = new CustomTableModel();                
   // listofitemtable.setModel(cusTablModel);        
    listofitemtable.setModel(model);
     listofitemtable.setRowHeight(75);
    listofitemtable.getColumnModel().getColumn(8).setPreferredWidth(50);
   // listofitemtable.setModel(model);
}
catch (SQLException e) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage());
}
}
```

Comment: I'd start with [How to Use Tables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) as it will describe the core requirements. `JTable` is capable of "automatically" displaying a `ImageIcon` if the `columnClass` reported by the `TableModel` provides the correct class type.

Comment: You might also consider [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29983710/displaying-images-from-mysql-database-on-a-single-column-of-jtable/29983992#29983992) which can load images from the database - it's possible that your `ImageIcon` is not a valid image file and therefore isn't been rendered

Comment: Not sure what this `listofitemtable.getColumn("image").setCellRenderer(new meetable()); ` is doing, but when you set a new model to the table, this will be discarded.

Comment: Thank you for response without button click jtable is working…. And image is showing