# How to display blob(image) from database to jlabel in java

Tags: java

I've read many articles and tutorials but still have not found a solution. I also read in some posts that are on stackoverflow but still have not found a solution. everything I ask for help to solve my problem. Thank you earlier. sorry for my English is garbled

```
try {
        int baris = tabelpelanggan.getSelectedRow();
        stt = K.PrepareStatement();
        rs = stt.executeQuery("select image from pelanggan where idpelanggan='"
                + tabelpelanggan.getValueAt(baris, 0).toString() + "'");
        byte[] imagee = null;
        while (rs.next()) {
            Blob blob = rs.getBlob("image");

            imagee = blob.getBytes(1, (int) blob.length());
        }

        Image i = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(imagee);
        ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon(i);
        Image iii = ii.getImage();
        Image newicon = iii.getScaledInstance(labelImage.getWidth(), labelImage.getHeight(), Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(newicon);
        labelImage.setIcon(icon);

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
```

Comment: You mean [something like this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13833089/how-to-show-an-image-from-ms-access-to-jpanel-in-java-netbeans/13833233#13833233)? [Or this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20752432/convert-bufferedinputstream-into-image/20753089#20753089)?

Comment: I've tried that you suggest but still not working. There is no error but on the jlabel nothing appears

Comment: Here's the problem, I have at least two examples, one which is fully runnable, which work, I don't even know the database you're using or how the image is stored in the database